# Python asyncio - consumer blocking with asyncio.Event()

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I have a program with one producer and two **slow** consumers and I'd like to rewrite it with coroutines in such way that each consumer will handle **only last value** (i.e. skip new values generated during processing the old ones) produced for it (I used threads and `threading.Queue()` but with it blocks on `put()`, cause the queue will be full most of the time).

After reading [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324346/how-do-i-connect-asyncio-coroutines-that-continually-produce-and-consume-data) I decided to use `asyncio.Event` and `asyncio.Queue`. I wrote this prototype program:

```
import asyncio

async def l(event, q):
    h = 1
    while True:
        # ready
        event.set()
        # get value to process
        a = await q.get()
        # process it
        print(a * h)
        h *= 2

async def m(event, q):
    i = 1
    while True:
        # pass element to consumer, when it's ready
        if event.is_set():
            await q.put(i)
            event.clear()
        # produce value
        i += 1

el = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ev = asyncio.Event()
qu = asyncio.Queue(2)
tasks = [
            asyncio.ensure_future(l(ev, qu)),
            asyncio.ensure_future(m(ev, qu))
        ]
el.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
el.close()
```

and I have noticed that `l` coroutine blocks on `q.get()` line and doesn't print anything.

It works as I expect after adding `asyncio.sleep()` in both (I get **1,11,21,...**):

```
import asyncio
import time

async def l(event, q):
    h = 1
    a = 1
    event.set()
    while True:
        # await asyncio.sleep(1)
        a = await q.get()
        # process it
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(a * h)
        event.set()

async def m(event, q):
    i = 1
    while True:
        # pass element to consumer, when it's ready
        if event.is_set():
            await q.put(i)
            event.clear()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        # produce value
        i += 1

el = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ev = asyncio.Event()
qu = asyncio.Queue(2)
tasks = [
            asyncio.ensure_future(l(ev, qu)),
            asyncio.ensure_future(m(ev, qu))
        ]
el.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
el.close()
```

...but I'm looking for solution without it.

Why is it so? How can I fix it? I think I cannot call `await l()` from `m` as both of them have states (in original program the first draws solution with PyGame and the second plots results).

Comment: Why not simply rely on the queue `maxsize`, instead of using an `Event`? (`queue.put` blocks until a slot is available in the queue)

Comment: @Vincent yes, right, but as I wrote at the beginning I don't want it to block on `put`. I had a solution with threads and `threading.Queue` but with it producer waits for the slowest consumer almost all the time. I'd like to try with coroutines and `asyncio.Event` behaviour baffles me, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is not working as expected as the task running the m function is never stopped. The task will continue increment i in the case that event.is_set() == False. Because this task is never suspended, the task running function l will never be called. Therefore, you need a way to suspend the task running function m. One way of suspending is awaiting another coroutine, that is the reason why a asyncio.sleep works as expected.

I think the following code will work as you expect. The LeakyQueue will ensure that only the last value from the producer will be processed by the consumer. As the complexity is very symmetric, the consumer will consume all values produced by the producer. If you increase the delay argument, you can simulate that the consumer only processes the last value created by the producer.

```
import asyncio

class LeakyQueue(asyncio.Queue):
    async def put(self, item):
        if self.full():
            await self.get()
        await super().put(item)

async def consumer(queue, delay=0):
    h = 1
    while True:
        a = await queue.get()
        if delay:
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        print ('consumer', a)
        h += 2

async def producer(queue):
    i = 1
    while True:
        await asyncio.ensure_future(queue.put(i))
        print ('producer', i)
        i += 1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = LeakyQueue(maxsize=1)
tasks = [
    asyncio.ensure_future(consumer(queue, 0)),
    asyncio.ensure_future(producer(queue))
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```